# How do I stop resize bar from being so glitchy?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, events

Basically, I want to make the resize bar move as I move the cursor across as long as I'm focusing on it. I did that but the thing is that it's being glitchy. It returns to the original state one time and the other time follows the cursor. I don't want it to do that.

```js
let slider = document.querySelector(".Slider");
let container = document.querySelector(".Container")
let contone = document.querySelector(".contone");
let conttwo = document.querySelector(".conttwo");
let clicked = false;

slider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    clicked = true;
    slider.style.left += e.offsetX + "px";
})

container.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(clicked) {
        slider.style.left = e.offsetX + "px"
        console.log("Cursor is " + e.offsetX)
        console.log("Element is" + slider.style.left)
    }
})

container.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    clicked = false;
})
```

```css
.Container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contone {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -11;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contone img {
    position: relative;
}

.conttwo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -11111;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.Slider {
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 1%;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
    <script src="Script.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="contone">
        <img
          class="Pic1"
          src="https://aluminumwheelsguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Best-All-Wheel-Drive-Cars-2020-700x300.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>        
      <div class="Slider"></div>
      <div class="conttwo">
        <img
          class="Pic2"
          src="https://signatureautoworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/SONATA-hero-option2-764A4983-640x354.jpg"
          alt=""
        />      
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, as you drag the element, it works but it isn't smooth. It returns to its original coordinates sometimes and then follows the cursor the other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.offsetX` is the mouse position relative to the element, so that makes the slider jump. `.clientX` is the mouse position relative to the document.

In order to use clientX, however, you need to subtract the original x position of the slider. I'm going to assume that `.Container` will always be the container for the slider. By using `getBoundingClientRect()` (which is a operation that takes time), I can get the x position (.left) from said container.

```js
let slider = document.querySelector(".Slider");
let container = document.querySelector(".Container")
let contone = document.querySelector(".contone");
let conttwo = document.querySelector(".conttwo");
let clicked = false;

slider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    clicked = true;
})

container.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(clicked) {
        updateSliderPosition(e.clientX);
        console.clear();
        console.log("Cursor is " + e.clientX);
        console.log("Element is" + slider.style.left);
    }
})

   function updateSliderPosition(value) {
        let box = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        slider.style.left = value - box.left + "px";
   }

container.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        clicked = false;
})
```

```css
.Container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contone {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -11;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contone img {
    position: relative;
}

.conttwo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -11111;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.Slider {
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 1%;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
    <script src="Script.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="contone">
        <img
          class="Pic1"
          src="https://aluminumwheelsguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Best-All-Wheel-Drive-Cars-2020-700x300.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>        
      <div class="Slider"></div>
      <div class="conttwo">
        <img
          class="Pic2"
          src="https://signatureautoworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/SONATA-hero-option2-764A4983-640x354.jpg"
          alt=""
        />      
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh. I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use a translation, which are generally considered better for animations than absolute positioning, for moving the slider.

I'm also using pointer events over mouse events. These work the same as mouse events but also will work for touch devices. They also allow the use of `setPointerCapture`, which means that once we have clicked on the slider, it will receive all events until we release it (which we do in the mouseUpHandler). You can see in the demo that even if the pointer goes outside the image, you can still move the slider around.

```js
let slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let sliderWidth = container.offsetWidth * (1 / 100);
let maxWidth = container.offsetWidth - sliderWidth;

let lastX = 0;
let thisX = 0;
let leftEdge = 0;

function mouseDownHandler(e) {
  lastX = e.clientX;

  slider.addEventListener('pointermove', mouseMoveHandler);
  slider.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  thisX = e.clientX;
  xDiff = thisX - lastX;
  leftEdge = Math.min(maxWidth, Math.max(0, leftEdge + xDiff));
  slider.style.transform = `translate(${leftEdge}px)`;
  lastX = thisX;
}

function mouseUpHandler(e) {
  slider.removeEventListener('pointermove', mouseMoveHandler);
  slider.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
}

slider.addEventListener("pointerdown", mouseDownHandler);
slider.addEventListener("pointerup", mouseUpHandler)
```

```css
.Container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contone,
.conttwo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contone {
  z-index: -11;
}

.conttwo {
  z-index: -11111;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Slider {
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 1%;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="Container">
  <div class="contone">
    <img class="Pic1" src="https://aluminumwheelsguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Best-All-Wheel-Drive-Cars-2020-700x300.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="slider" class="Slider"></div>

  <div class="conttwo">
    <img class="Pic2" src="https://signatureautoworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/SONATA-hero-option2-764A4983-640x354.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think of that before. Thank you!